# Laravel separate array into table fields

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table, data has been passed to it, and is being stored. I want to separate it into different columns of a table to make it easily readable.

When I use:

```
<td>{{$message->Content['text']}}</td>
```

I get the error: `Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: VIEWSDIRECTORY)`.

This is the dump of what seems to be pulling, I am trying to return the `"text":"SPOCK"` as I can then repeat the process for each one section i.e type:

```
 {
        #attributes: array:11 [
    "id" => "b5ef7556-c208-40b0-8bfa-1358bf482cd0"
    "method" => "sms"
    "msisdn" => 6422
    "direction" => "mo"
    "type" => "suggestion"
    "status" => "received"
    "content" => "{"senderPhoneNumber":"+6422","messageId":"Ms5ppMnxRHTw26gFSRwbsvAA","sendTime":"2020-06-05T03:20:58.506749Z","suggestionResponse":{"postbackData":"49da99a5-bc85-4efd-9587-54c335e7f329","text":"SPOCK","type":"REPLY"}}"
    "suggestion_id" => "49da99a5-bc85-4efd-9587-54c335e7f329"
    "created_at" => 1591327269
    "updated_at" => 1591327269
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
```

My controller:

```
    {
        $message = Message::find($id);

        return view($message->direction . $message->type, compact('message'));
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">MESSAGE ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">MESSAGE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style='font-size:14px'>{{$message->id}}</td>    
            <td>{{$message->Content['text']}}</td>
```

My Message Model:

```
    /**
     * Get the suggestions for this message.
     */
    public function suggestions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Suggestion::class);
    }

    public function getContentAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }
```

Comment: Please put here $message variable value

Comment: Where do I put this, i have put $message in the <td>

Comment: Do you have any relationship in Message model ?

Comment: @KhalidKhan I have updated my question to include the message Model, there's not much to it though, all the data is linked inside the db as: `{"senderPhoneNumber":"+12314","messageId":"M231dsa","sendTime":"2020-06-05T01:45:48.959577Z","Response":{"postbackData":"11612930-bb54-4e36-bfaa-8c7b7607675e","text":"TESTER TESTER ","type":"REPLY"}}`

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you could reduce the code to a [mcve] - we don't need any of your script includes, checks on status, etc, and the controller code you've shown has about 17 `use` statements that aren't actually referenced in your sample. Since you've only got one item, even the fact that the output is an HTML table is irrelevant - just try to output one particular value, and show us that code and the exact output it gives you.

Comment: @IMSoP that's fair, I'll try my best to reduce further questions. I see your point though and I'll do an edit.

Comment: @IMSoP is that the sort of tidy up you had in mind? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Is that JSON the value of `content` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like (not clear in the question) that the JSON you posted is the value of the `content` field of your `Message` model, right? If so, you are trying to access `text` directly while its inside the `Response` property.

So your view should be like:

```
<td>{{$message->content->Response->text}}</td>
```

Comment: I just noticed that actually! I think you're right I will give this a try first thing in the morning!!! Even looking at the DB it appears to be nested inside the response { }

Comment: Okay so if I put through as `<td>{{$message->content->Response->text}}</td>` I get the same error but its reference to response instead of text. However if I do `<td>{{$message->Response->text}}</td>` I get a non-object error. Is there anyway this is helpful to getting us closer to finding fix?

Comment: Here is the official error: `Trying to get property 'text' of non-object`

Comment: I tried a new way and it gave some success or indicates some success if you have any ideas let me know :)